# Disable TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1 in Apache Kafka

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, tls1.2

I am trying to disable TLS 1.0, 1.1 for a Kafka cluster.

I have added this configuration in kafka/config/server.properties file, hoping that it accept only TLS 1.2 traffic and the rest will be blocked.

> ssl.enabled.protocols=TLSv1.2

It doesnt seem to have taken any effect.

It is a 3 node cluster, so I basically added this config to each kafka node manually and restarted it.

What Am I missing here ?

Comment: How are you determining if it is rejecting TLS 1.0 and 1.1 connections?

Comment: I use openssl to verify -> openssl s_client -connect hostname:9092 -tls1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It did work after I figured that I was applying this config on a wrong config file.

Apparently they had customised the project structure different from the default one.